# (CLOSED)Adding Google maps to Appengine

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am having problems with adding google maps to my webapp on google appengine. It works fine when I run it [locally](http://www.upload.ee/image/3895354/Capture.JPG).

My index.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/mingitegevus.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/map_canvas_initialize().js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Spordikaart</title>
  </head>

  <body>    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <p id="test">Vinge programm</p>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <form><input type='button' value="Touch me" onclick="touch()";></form>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="map_canvas" class="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So map_canvas_initialize().js does not work/load. Appengines log does not tell much either:

```
/js/map_canvas_initialize().js 200 81ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36 module=default version=1
90.213.123.96 - - [18/Feb/2014:04:51:12 -0800] "GET /js/map_canvas_initialize().js HTTP/1.1" 200 59 "http://spordikaart.appspot.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36" "spordikaart.appspot.com" ms=81 cpu_ms=2902 cpm_usd=0.000007 app_engine_release=1.8.9 instance=00c61b117c9fde1367f47afa69ce18e068eec8
```

map_canvas_initialize().js is following:

```
var initialLocation;
var browserSupportFlag = new Boolean();
var l = new google.maps.LatLng(52, 22);

function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom : 18,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        browserSupportFlag = true;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        });
    } else {
        browserSupportFlag = false;
        handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    }

    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag == true) {
            alert("Geolocation service failed");
            initialLocation = l;
        } else {
            alert("Browser does not support geolocation.");
            initialLocation = l;
        }
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Kaart</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.kaart.KaartServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Kaart</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Kaart</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Kaart</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Project sturcture:
[image: Project structure]

Any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: Have you tried to use a filename without the parentheses?

Comment: Why do you have so strange name for script file? `map_canvas_initialize().js`? It is like function name.

Comment: @Dr.Molle&&@Anto Jurković this must be stupidest mistake I've ever made. I put the parentheses out of habit of calling java functions out like this and never thought that this kind of thing could cause any errors. Now I removed them and everything work just fine. Thank you so much!